# Leaving Canada - sole parent with child consent

Tags: canada, children

I will soon be visiting Canada for the first time, as part of a multi-stop journey with my daughter. I bought a one-way ticket for the leg from Canada to Europe and the (Canadian) agent pointed out the requirement to have a notarised letter from my daughter's mother consenting to her travelling with me alone. The T&Cs accompanying the ticket confirmation set out the requirement.

This is the first time I have encountered such a requirement. My question is whether the requirement is really necessary - how often do the Canadian authorities actually ask to see this letter, and how difficult would things be if I were not able to produce it?

Comment: [This](http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/children/consent-letter) looks like the information you want.

Comment: I never had any such requests, but I imagine they're trained to profile and if your daughter is moody or cranky that day..

Comment: I wouldn't think about traveling with a child without both parents without such a letter, period.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is a requirement and is usually checked by immigration, much before you get to the crossing point. My wife had to do it several times and its a quite simply and fast process. We used a [letter](http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/children/consent-letter) provided by the Government of Canada site and had brought it to city hall to have it certified. The process took a few mins for a nominal fee (under $10 IIRC).

Once I did not have that document because the mother was nowhere to be found and instead presented the court order awarding me sole custody of the children when immigration asked about the mother. That also worked but required more checking. The former is more common, so if you can have the letter and the mother sign it, it would be best.